# Read specific part of a filehandle in PERL

Tags: perl

Hi I have a large file I would like to read.  To save resource I want to read it slowly, one line at a time.  However I'm wondering if there is a way to read specific line from a filehandle instead.  For example, say I have a test.txt file containing a billion numbers starting with 1.  Each number is on a separate line.

```
1
2
3
...
```

so now what I currently do to get say line 10 is this,

```
open (FILE, "< test.txt") or die "$!"; 
@reads = <FILE>
print $reads[9];
```

however, is there a way I can access certain part of the FILE without reading everything into a big array, say I want line 10 instead.

```
something like FILE->[9]
```

-
thanks for helping in advance!

Comment: Hi, found the answer with a perl module; description says that it does not read into memory.

`use Tie::File;

tie @array, 'Tie::File', 'test.txt' or die;

print "$array[9]";`

Comment: The docs on Tie::File scare me: http://search.cpan.org/~toddr/Tie-File-1.00/lib/Tie/File.pm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods, do line by line processing your skip to the desired line.  You can use the Input Line Number variable, [`$.`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) to help:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my $line10 = sub {
    open my $fh, '<', 'text.txt';
    while (<$fh>) {
        return $_ if $. == 10;
    }
}->();
```

Alternatively, you could use [`Tie::File`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html) as you already noticed.  However, while that interface is very convenient, and I'd recommend it's use, it also will loop through the file behind the scenes.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

use Tie::File;

tie my @array, 'Tie::File', 'text.txt' or die "Can't open text.txt: $!";

print $array[9] // die "Line 10 does not exist";
```

Answer (score 1):

For memory purposes large files should be read in using a while loop which will read the file line by line:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'somefile.txt';
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
   //read in text line by line
}
```

Either way to get at that line number you are going to have to read the whole file in. Now I would recommend using the while loop and a counter to print / save the line you are looking for.

Comment: cool thanks; actually found a module that can actually do it without reading into memory; its called Tie::File

Comment: There's no need for a counter; you can simply write a test for one of Perl's special vars, `$.`

Comment: @Steve thanks; this is very useful - I can totally use as well.